# TYPO3: Realurl duplicate slash with tx_news - resolved but not understood

Tags: php, typo3, tx-news, realurl

I'm simply using the official realurl conf on the tx_news [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/AdministratorManual/BestPractice/Realurl/Index.html). That caused a duplicate slash in my url. It would look like that:

domain.com/post//post-title

To fix it, I found out that I either have to remove or place the following lines after the tx_newspil[news] inside the fixedPostVars:

Before:

```
'fixedPostVars' => [
    'newsDetailConfiguration' => [
        [
            'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
            'valueMap' => [
                '' => 'detail',
            ],
            'noMatch' => 'bypass'
        ],
        [
            'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
            'valueMap' => [
                '' => 'detail',
            ],
            'noMatch' => 'bypass'
        ],
        [
            'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[news]',
            'lookUpTable' => [
                'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
                'id_field' => 'uid',
                'alias_field' => 'IF(path_segment!="",path_segment,title)',
                'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                'languageExceptionUids' => '',
                'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
                'expireDays' => 180,
                'enable404forInvalidAlias' => true
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

After:

```
'fixedPostVars' => [
    'newsDetailConfiguration' => [
        [
            'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[news]',
            'lookUpTable' => [
                'table' => 'tx_news_domain_model_news',
                'id_field' => 'uid',
                'alias_field' => 'IF(path_segment!="",path_segment,title)',
                'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                'languageGetVar' => 'L',
                'languageExceptionUids' => '',
                'languageField' => 'sys_language_uid',
                'transOrigPointerField' => 'l10n_parent',
                'expireDays' => 180,
                'enable404forInvalidAlias' => true
            ]
        ],
        [
            'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[action]',
            'valueMap' => [
                '' => 'detail',
            ],
            'noMatch' => 'bypass'
        ],
        [
            'GETvar' => 'tx_news_pi1[controller]',
            'valueMap' => [
                '' => 'detail',
            ],
            'noMatch' => 'bypass'
        ]
    ]
]
```

Either switching them or simply deleting the controller / action parts fixed the duplicate slash. Now I'd like to understand why that is so, since im a PHP beginner I don't really get it.

I appreciate all the help!

** Just tested, only the action part had to be moved or deleted in order to resolve the duplicate slash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the `REALURL` configuration gets parameters in the order you add.

Let's take the first `REALURL` configuration from your post. Within this configuration I expect my URL be so: `/page/action/controller/post-title`.

What happens there is that you have the news plugin with `action` and `controller` params set in the post page and then you don't pass the `action` and `controller` in the `URL`, that's why you have `double slashes` there, because `action` and `controller` are empty.

> Default parameters (e.q controller name, action name, etc), parameters where the value is not required, must be at the end of the configuration, like your last configuration.

Comment: Seems plausible, I thought the nomatch bypass property is there to skip it if it's empty though.. Thanks anyway.